# Give React setState parameters variable value

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to create a function handleFalse() in react so it works something like:

```
state = {
  Java: false,
  Python: false
}

handleFalse(language) {
  this.setState({language}:true);
}

render() {
  return(
    <Modal onHide={this.handleFalse("show")}></Modal>
  )
}
```

where language would be one of Java or Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a computed property like this:

```js
handleTrue(language) {
  this.setState({ [language]: true });
}
```

You can reference an object property with a variable by using `[]`.

This works when accessing too: `this.state[language]`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an error saying "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." Do you know why?

Comment: That's going to be unrelated to this code here, and most likely caused by where you are calling the function. Can you show how you are calling it?

Comment: Change to `onHide={() => this.handleFalse("show")}`. The way it is currently you are calling the `handleFalse` function every render, which sets state, which causes a re-render, and then repeats infinitely.

Comment: `onHide={() => doSomething()}` is assigning `onHide` a function. `onHide={doSomething()}` is assigning `onHide` the value of whatever `doSomething` returns.